# How can I join an array of numbers into 1 concatenated number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I join this array to give me expected output in as few steps as possible?

```
var x = [31,31,3,1]
//expected output: x = 313131;
```

Comment: `x = +x.join('')`, probably. This is not very interesting code golf.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use array `join` method.`Join` joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string. The default separator is comma (,). Here the separator should be an empty string.

```
var  x = [31,31,3,1].join("");
```

EDIT: To get the result as numeric

```
const  x = +[31,31,3,1].join("");
```

or

```
const  x = Number([31,31,3,1].join(""));
```

Comment: That would return a String.@MatthewHarwood asked to return an integer. For achieving that you should wrap up the result: 
`x = parseInt(x);`

Comment: Thank you @Pablo, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Javascript [join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) will give you the expected output as `string`. If you want it as a `number`, do this:

```
var x = [31,31,3,1];
var xAsString = x.join(''); // Results in a string
var xAsNumber = Number(x.join('')); // Results in a number, you can also use +(x.join(''))
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of anything other than

```
+Function.call.apply(String.prototype.concat, x)
```

or, if you insist

```
+''.concat.apply('', x)
```

In ES6:

```
+''.concat(...x)
```

Using `reduce`:

```
+x.reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');
```

Or if you prefer

```
x.reduce(Function.call.bind(String.prototype.concat), '')
```

Another idea is to manipulate the array as a string, always a good approach.

```
+String.prototype.replace.call(x, /,/g, '')
```

There may be other ways. Perhaps a Google search on "join array javascript" would turn up some obscure function which joins elements of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks for a number, most of the answers above are going to give you a string. You want something like this.

`const number = Number([31,31,3,1].join(""));`

Answer (score 0):

Try join() as follows

```js
var x = [31,31,3,1]
var y = x.join('');
alert(y);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below.

```
var x = [31,31,3,1]
var teststring = x.join("");
```

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
var x = [31,31,3,1];
var result = x.join("");
```